# ANDROID: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/mysql/cj/MysqlType

Tags: java, android, mysql, mysql-connector

I'm trying to connect my proyect with a mysql database but I get this error at the driver:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.example.catalyst, PID: 12531
        java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/mysql/cj/MysqlType;
            at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.findMysqlType(NativeProtocol.java:1466)
            at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.ColumnDefinitionReader.unpackField(ColumnDefinitionReader.java:134)
            at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.ColumnDefinitionReader.read(ColumnDefinitionReader.java:77)
            at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.ColumnDefinitionReader.read(ColumnDefinitionReader.java:40)
            at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.read(NativeProtocol.java:1588)
            at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.TextResultsetReader.read(TextResultsetReader.java:68)
            at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.TextResultsetReader.read(TextResultsetReader.java:48)
            at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.read(NativeProtocol.java:1601)
            at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.readAllResults(NativeProtocol.java:1655)
            at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.loadServerVariables(NativeSession.java:765)
            at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.initializePropsFromServer(ConnectionImpl.java:1303)
            at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:964)
            at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:823)
            at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:453)
            at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246)
            at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198)
            at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:569)
            at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:219)
            at modelo.Conexion.conectar(Conexion.java:24)
            at modelo.EnviarIngresos.ejecutarServicio(EnviarIngresos.java:27)
            at GUIs.QRscanner.enviarIngreso(QRscanner.java:75)
            at GUIs.QRscanner.onClick(QRscanner.java:42)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6297)
            at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24797)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6626)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:811)
         Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.cj.MysqlType
            at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:738)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:363)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
            at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.findMysqlType(NativeProtocol.java:1466) 
            at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.ColumnDefinitionReader.unpackField(ColumnDefinitionReader.java:134) 
            at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.ColumnDefinitionReader.read(ColumnDefinitionReader.java:77) 
            at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.ColumnDefinitionReader.read(ColumnDefinitionReader.java:40) 
            at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.read(NativeProtocol.java:1588) 
            at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.TextResultsetReader.read(TextResultsetReader.java:68) 
            at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.TextResultsetReader.read(TextResultsetReader.java:48) 
            at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.read(NativeProtocol.java:1601) 
            at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.readAllResults(NativeProtocol.java:1655) 
            at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.loadServerVariables(NativeSession.java:765) 
            at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.initializePropsFromServer(ConnectionImpl.java:1303) 
            at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:964) 
            at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:823) 
            at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:453) 
            at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246) 
            at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198) 
            at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:569) 
            at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:219) 
            at modelo.Conexion.conectar(Conexion.java:24) 
            at modelo.EnviarIngresos.ejecutarServicio(EnviarIngresos.java:27) 
            at GUIs.QRscanner.enviarIngreso(QRscanner.java:75) 
            at GUIs.QRscanner.onClick(QRscanner.java:42) 
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6297) 
            at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119) 
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24797) 
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790) 
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6626) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:811) 
         Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/sql/SQLType;
            at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.findMysqlType(NativeProtocol.java:1466) 
            at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.ColumnDefinitionReader.unpackField(ColumnDefinitionReader.java:134) 
            at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.ColumnDefinitionReader.read(ColumnDefinitionReader.java:77) 
            at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.ColumnDefinitionReader.read(ColumnDefinitionReader.java:40) 
            at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.read(NativeProtocol.java:1588) 
            at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.TextResultsetReader.read(TextResultsetReader.java:68) 
            at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.TextResultsetReader.read(TextResultsetReader.java:48) 
            at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.read(NativeProtocol.java:1601) 
            at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.readAllResults(NativeProtocol.java:1655) 
            at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.loadServerVariables(NativeSession.java:765) 
            at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.initializePropsFromServer(ConnectionImpl.java:1303) 
            at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:964) 
            at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:823) 
            at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:453) 
            at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246) 
            at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198) 
            at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:569) 
            at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:219) 
            at modelo.Conexion.conectar(Conexion.java:24) 
            at modelo.EnviarIngresos.ejecutarServicio(EnviarIngresos.java:27) 
            at GUIs.QRscanner.enviarIngreso(QRscanner.java:75) 
            at GUIs.QRscanner.onClick(QRscanner.java:42) 
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6297) 
            at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119) 
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24797) 
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790) 
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6626) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:811) 
         Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "java.sql.SQLType" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.catalyst-r_unhHUpn3kJ_xqUGFYc4w==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.catalyst-fumFeudS3H2K2UqSBclr7A==/lib/arm, /system/lib, /system/vendor/lib]]
            at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:125)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
            at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.findMysqlType(NativeProtocol.java:1466) 
            at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.ColumnDefinitionReader.unpackField(ColumnDefinitionReader.java:134) 
            at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.ColumnDefinitionReader.read(ColumnDefinitionReader.java:77) 
            at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.ColumnDefinitionReader.read(ColumnDefinitionReader.java:40) 
            at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.read(NativeProtocol.java:1588) 
            at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.TextResultsetReader.read(TextResultsetReader.java:68) 
            at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.TextResultsetReader.read(TextResultsetReader.java:48) 
            at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.read(NativeProtocol.java:1601) 
            at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.readAllResults(NativeProtocol.java:1655) 
            at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.loadServerVariables(NativeSession.java:765) 
            at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.initializePropsFromServer(ConnectionImpl.java:1303) 
            at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:964) 
            at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:823) 
            at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:453) 
            at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246) 
            at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198) 
            at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:569) 
            at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:219) 
            at modelo.Conexion.conectar(Conexion.java:24) 
            at modelo.EnviarIngresos.ejecutarServicio(EnviarIngresos.java:27) 
            at GUIs.QRscanner.enviarIngreso(QRscanner.java:75) 
            at GUIs.QRscanner.onClick(QRscanner.java:42) 
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6297) 
            at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119) 
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24797) 
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790) 
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6626) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:811)
```

These are my dependencies(gradle):

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.1'

    implementation files('libs\\UMLDesignTool.jar')
    implementation files('libs/mysql-connector-java-8.0.25.jar')
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.4.0'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.4.0'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher:1.0.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter'
    androidTestImplementation 'org.testng:testng:6.9.6'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.0'

}
```

And this is the class of my project where I do the connection:

```
import android.os.StrictMode;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class Conexion {
    private static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver";
    private static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/databasename";
    private static final String USER = "root";
    private static final String PASS = "";


    public Connection conectar(){

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

        Connection conexion = null;

        try {
            Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER).newInstance();
            conexion= DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return conexion;
    }
    
}
```

The error says that I don't have the driver but I do, I don't know what to do and I can't find any post that has the same error as me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot use recent versions of MySQL Connector/J on Android, because it uses types and features not available on Android. The specific reason here is that the type `com.mysql.cj.MysqlType` implements `java.sql.SQLType` (introduced in Java 8 / JDBC 4.2), and judging by the error this type does not exist in Android. In the past, I have also seen errors related to using named groups in regular expressions, which are (or were) also not supported on Android.

In general, you shouldn't use JDBC on Android, and it is better to use a REST API to mediate between your Android application and a database. However, if you really want to use MySQL from Android, you will have to use MySQL Connector/J 5.1.x instead of 8.0.x.