# Trouble querying Oracle database in Android app with Java

Tags: java, android, sql, oracle, android-studio

I'm currently working on an Android app that needs to fetch data from an Oracle database using Java. I've already written code for this purpose, which runs perfectly in IntelliJ IDEA, but when I try to run the same code in my Android app, I encounter issues. I have connected oracle drivers.
I know its maybe not the best way to connect database directly, but it's on our university's server, so we're dependent on it.
Error:  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/sql/DriverAction;

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView textView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textView = findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    AppCompatButton button = findViewById(R.id.button);

    button.setOnClickListener(l -> {
        try {
            validateLogin();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    });
}

public void validateLogin() throws SQLException {

    DatabaseConnection connnectNow = new DatabaseConnection();
    Connection connectDB = connnectNow.getConnection();


    String countUsers = "SELECT ... FROM ...";
    Statement statement = connectDB.createStatement();
    ResultSet queryResult = statement.executeQuery(countUsers);
    while (queryResult.next()) {
        textView.setText(...);
    }
}
```

}

```
public class DatabaseConnection {

public Connection databaseLink;

public Connection getConnection() {

    String databaseUser = "...";
    String databasePassword = "...";
    String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@...:...:orcl";

    try {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        databaseLink = DriverManager.getConnection(url, databaseUser, databasePassword);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return databaseLink;
}
```

}

Comment: Did you check this already? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68508321/android-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-failed-resolution-of-lcom-mysql-cj-mys I am really not sure, that you have drivers for Oracle on your Android device...

Answer (score 0):

while I was working with java database connection I faced the same issue of driver not loading then I changed the dependencies the xml file and it worked fine for me .
so try changing the dependencies it should work fine then.